# ConcurrentDictionary<string,ArrayList> AddOrUpdate error

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrentdictionary

I stumbled upon the following obstacle. I need to have a ConcurrentDictionary<string, ArrayList> which has string as key and ArrayList as value. I want to use the AddOrUpdate in the following manner:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ArrayList> _data= new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ArrayList>();

private void AddData(string key, string message){
     _data.AddOrUpdate(key, new ArrayList() { message }, (string existingKey, string existingList) => existingList.Add(message));

}
```

However this method does not work and throws the following error:

> Compiler Error CS1661: Cannot convert anonymous method block to delegate type 'delegate type' because the specified block's parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types

See [link to error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1661?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1661))

In conclusion, I am trying to do the following:

1. Try adding message to arraylist in the ConcurrentDictionary.
2. If arraylist DOES NOT exist, create a new one with the message in it.
3. If arraylist DOES exist, simply add it to the end of the array.

So my question is, how can I fix this error and improve my code, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Pro tip, don't use ArrayList, its an ancient relic of. NET

Comment: your lambda should *return* new value for key, not just modify existing value inplace. Moreover, even if you will return modified value, I'm afraid that such a modifying is not thread-safe

Comment: What would you suggest using ?

Comment: Microsoft recommends to use List<T> instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0

Comment: Please don't use fairly complex collections such as `ConcurrentDictionary` unless you have a good grasp at writing multi-threaded code already, and you understand the pitfalls. You're not thinking about the fact that any modifications to the ArrayList need to be thread-safe as well, for example. You're probably going to be much better off using a simple lock around a `Dictionary`

Comment: The idea is that I am making a sample mechanism, in this mechanism im keeping counts in specified keys. Like "firstKey" has value: "3" . every time when this reaches some boundary, the message that it comes with, will be sampled. I haven't included this in the questoin as it's not important. However I am sure that I have achieved thread safety because the counts are also kept in a concurrentdictionary.

Comment: The factory parameters of a concurrent collection are safe from the perspective the internal consistency of the collection however they can run more than once when there is contention . There is no internal lock purse

Comment: schweppes0x the "update" in the name `AddOrUpdate` means replace the existing value with another one, not modify the existing value. The `ConcurrentDictionary` offers no protection against concurrent mutations by multiple threads for the values it contains, in case these are mutable objects.

Comment: What method would you guys suggest in this situation?  how would i keep an count otherwise of these unique keys ? Every one of these keys can have multiple collected messages and this increases as the count goes up.

Comment: @schweppes0x I recommend what I said above -- use a simple `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and a separate lock. Acquire the lock before querying or updating the dictionary

Comment: How would I be sure that no lock contention would occur because there will be flying at least 400.000 messages a day through the application. @canton7

Comment: You can't be sure there's no lock contention -- that's the point of a lock. But 400,000/day is about 4.5/second, which is nothing. The stuff inside the lock should take single-digit microseconds, so contention is very unlikely

Comment: Note that ConcurrentDictionary doesn't avoid lock contention either, and in fact it behaves *worse* than a simple Dictionary+lock for many usage patterns

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to do it with the Dictionary+lock method!

Comment: I am not sure why the ConcurrentDictionary is worse than a lock+Dictionary, would you like to explain or direct me towards some kind of source ? I even found some sources saying that the performance of ConcurrentDictionary are far better than the lock+dict

Comment: @schweppes0x IIRC, ConcurrentDictionary is optimized for heavy contention -- a lot of effort goes into fine-grained locking, for example. The worst-case behaviour of ConcurrentDictionary is pretty good, but it comes at the cost of less-than-ideal behaviour in scenarios with less contention.

Comment: @schweppes0x - Your code isn't throwing an error; it's unable to compile according to the error you've linked to. Can you confirm you have the right error?

Comment: schweppes0x you could check out this question: [ConcurrentDictionary with multiple values per key, removing empty entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695167/concurrentdictionary-with-multiple-values-per-key-removing-empty-entries). If you don't have the requirement of removing empty lists from the dictionary, then the answer to your problem is in the body of that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct thread-safe way is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;

private ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> _data = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>();

private void AddData(string key, string message){
     var list = _data.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new List<string>());

     lock(list) 
     {
        list.Add(message);
     } 

}
```